# cin.clear(ios_base::failbit) vs cin.setstate(ios_base::failbit)

Tags: c++, istream

For one of my assignments, I was told to use `cin.clear(ios_base::failbit)` to set the `failbit`.  I wonder, what is the difference between `cin.clear(ios_base::failbit)` and `cin.setstate(ios_base::failbit)`?  Is the latter not clearer?  I am a bit surprised to see how the `failbit` is set with `clear()`.  Why such a counter-intuitive way for using `clear()`?

Comment: Thank you for the editing.  I am not well versed in it.

Answer (score 5):

> I am a bit surprised to see how the fail bit is set with clear(). Why such a counter-intuitive way for using clear()?

Well let's think about it.

```
 std::cin.setstate(ios_base::failbit);
```

This will set the fail bit if it isn't already set, but preserve any other [stream error state](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdstate) for `std::cin`.

```
 std::cin.clear(ios_base::failbit);
```

This will clear all the stream error state from `std::cin` and then set only the fail bit.

Comment: Yes, that's why I am surprised.  I would only act on the fail bit and leave other bits alone.  This is an exercise in the Deitel C++ 9ed book, chapter 12.

Answer (score 3):

`setstate` and `clear` do different operations. They are not the same.

`setstate` actually calls `clear` with extra operation.

Basically, `setstate` is somehow **adding extra flag** while `clear` is to **override the whole thing**.

See here:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/setstate/

> Modifies the current internal error state flags by combining the current flags with those in argument state (as if performing a bitwise OR operation).
>   ...
>   This function behaves as if defined as:

```
void ios::setstate (iostate state) {
  clear(rdstate()|state);   //setstate is doing a OR operation while clear does not.
}
```

or here:http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/setstate

> Sets the stream error flags state in addition to currently set flags. Essentially calls clear(rdstate() | state).

Experiment code for VC++:

First find out how are the `iostate` constant implemented:

```
//Windows Visual C++ implementation
static constexpr _Iostate goodbit = (_Iostate)0x0;
static constexpr _Iostate eofbit = (_Iostate)0x1;
static constexpr _Iostate failbit = (_Iostate)0x2;
static constexpr _Iostate badbit = (_Iostate)0x4;
```

Then:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //eof 1, fail 2.
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    cout << stream.rdstate() << endl;  // should get 2
    stream.setstate(ios_base::eofbit);
    cout << stream.rdstate() << endl; // should get 3
    stream.clear(ios_base::eofbit);
    cout << stream.rdstate() << endl; // should get 1

}
```